# SSH working locally but not remotely

Tags: 16.04, ssh, openssh

I have already opened a SSH session on my PC and it worked perfectly with my laptop when connected to the same network. But now, when I'm at a different location, I can't connect.

I've already tried to edit the `/etc/hosts.allow` by adding

```
sshd : ALL : allow
```

But, it didn't work.
Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: You need to do port forwarding on your router (NAT). In most cases this is not related to Ubuntu and it is off-topic here. My answer from the suggested duplication explains how to do that according the common case when this question is asked :)

Comment: it isnt the router problem cause we used this pc as server. We changed ubuntu version from 18 to 16 and now we are having this issue.